# respond_to :json behaving very oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Controller:

```
class ThingController < ActionController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    puts "CREATE " + params.inspect
  end
end
```

and a test:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "/thing" do
  context "create" do
    it "should get params" do
      params = {"a" => "b", "c" => ["d"], "e" => [], "f"=>"",
                "g"=>nil, , "controller" => "NOPE", "action" => "NOPE"}
      post uri, params
    end
  end 
end
```

When I run this, the following is logged:

```
CREATE {"a"=>"b", "c"=>["d"], "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"thing"}
```

My questions are:

- where did `e` go? I would expect it to deserialize to an empty array, not to nothing at all.
- why are the `action` and `controller` params being mixed into this? Aren't the body and the rails internals completely separate concerns?
- Because of this, my `action` and `controller` JSON fields were over-written. How would I access these?
- Is this therefore not the right way to accept JSON?

I'm new to Rails, but I have done a lot of Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem: you need to ensure that your parameters are being sent as JSON, and also that they are being interpreted as JSON.

Essentially, you have to

- encode your parameters as JSON
- set appropriate content-type and accepts headers

See [POSTing raw JSON data with Rails 3.2.11 and RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775998/posting-raw-json-data-with-rails-3-2-11-and-rspec) for the way.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was following an example which must be slightly broken.

Answer (score 0):

The rails middleware will add the action and controller params so you'll have to put those in a nested hash if you still want to access your custom values.

Try adding `format: 'json'` to the params in your test. This will send a different content-type header and might help serialize the params correctly in order to keep the e param.