# Request spec: How to create a new user via POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, rspec

Given the following controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
      include ActionController::ImplicitRender
      include ActionController::ParamsWrapper

      wrap_parameters format: :json
      # POST /users
      # POST /users.json
      def create
        #@user = User.new(params[:user])
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
          render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
        else
          render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
        end
end
```

I am able to create a new user by sending a HTTP POST request with CURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@example.com"}' http://myrailsapp.dev/users
```

How would I craft the request spec accordingly?

```
  # spec/requests/users_spec.rb
  describe "POST /users" do
    it "should create a new user" do

      # FILL ME IN

      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
```

My first idea was to add the following:

```
post users_path, body: '{"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@example.com"}'
```

which results in a HTTP status of 400.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775998/posting-raw-json-data-with-rails-3-2-11-and-rspec

Comment: that fixed it. If you write it as a reply, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually your first comment, (which you sadly deleted) was the working answer: `      post users_path, user: {name: "Test", email: "xyz@example.com" }`   

There seems to be no need to pass the CONTENT_TYPE.

Comment: because after that I found the same question, just linked that and flagged your questions as duplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
post users_path, :user => {"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@example.com"}, { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'}
```

Comment: I just noticed, that this results in an error: 

`syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => (SyntaxError)
...post users_path, user: {"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@example.co...`

Also see comments under my question for refernce.

Comment: Updated, should be fine now

Comment: Nope. Problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the headers, you need to assure it specifies JSON content!

```
post users_path, '{"name":"xyz","email":"xyz@example.com"}' , { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }
```

Hope that works for you!
Cheers, Jan

Comment: Thx Jan. Toms comment above actually fixed it.

Comment: Great! Glad we got it out of the way!